# SharePoint 2007: Create or add zone without Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Can anyone provide instructions or a URL to add a new zone to a SharePoint site without Designer?

Right now, I have a site that only has a left and right zone and I want to add a 'Top' zone above the left and right zone.

Is there something in the site settings I can go to to add a new zone?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually talking about a page, not a site. The answer is no. What you can do is create a Web Part page based on a template that fits your needs.