# Sharepoint Foundation - Create page with zones

Tags: sharepoint, page-layout, zone, sharepointfoundation2010

I would like to create a page with default left and right zone, but I'm just able to create a rich page with column-based text layouts.
How can I achieve that? Are there some kind of templates?

Setup: Sharepoint Foundation 2010 (without access to SP Designer)
I also learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453956/sharepoint-2007-create-or-add-zone-without-designer), that I'm not able to create custom layouts without designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for:

- *All Site Content* in the Quick Launch bar
- Create
- Category *Pages and Sites*
- **Web Part Page**

Now I can choose a default layout template with multiple column combination.
As [detailCode stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17956857/1501824), I'm unable to create my own templates without SP Designer

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have the full SharePoint Server, if you want to make a page with custom zones, use SharePoint Designer to make your web part pages.

Put your zones in placeholdermain (Left/Right), then attached the default masterpage.  Use HTML tables to layout who you want the zones to appear in the ASPX.  It will look just like a page layout from SharePoint Server.  If you need a reference, look at default.aspx on the root of any site.

Also, place these kinds of files in a document library with versioning turned on.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately I don't have access to SP Designer due to company restrictions